# What is the value of $p(z) \log(z)$ around a contour centered on the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

Given a polynomial $p(z)$, and a rectangle with vertices $2+iM, -3+iM, -3-iM, 2-iM$ what is the value of $f(z) = p(z) \log(z)$ around the contour? Or equivalently the change in argument?

In particular I'm looking at how the change in argument grows as $M$ grows. The particular polynomial I'm interested in is only quadratic, however I'd like to know if it's possible to solve this problem more generally.

Comment: Warning: branch cuts. I assume you want the contour integral in the limiting case w/o hitting the cut.

Comment: @ChrisK Exactly.

Comment: The answer is dependent upon what branch of $\log$ you are assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we define $\log(z) = \log(|z|) + \arg(z)i$ where the branch cut is the positive real axis. Note that the only part of the integral that matters is the part with $\log$. Why? Then integrating we get:

$$2\pi i\cdot [\Sigma_{n=0}^{N} a_{n}\cdot \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}|_{z=2}]$$ where $p(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_{n}z^n$.

Clearly, this generalises easily to arbitrary polynomials. Also note that for clockwise integration, there is a change of sign.

Comment: I'm sorry, the $f(z)$ is the solution to an indefinite integral so you shouldn't need to integrate. Also can you change the branch cut to somewhere else, for the same solution?

Comment: @prince_muishkin, okay. Misinterpreted what you meant. I thought $p(z)\cdot \log(z)$ was the integrand. Also, the function is not holomorphic. If you change the branch cut, you change the answer.